# Create a webservice in Php native

Tags: php, web-services, native, using

I am new in web service. I was totally confused when seeing examples to create web service in internet. Actually, My client have xml to place the orders. what they want is they need to create a wsdl(web service) to call the xml by their vendor forms. So i need to create a webservice that integrate with xml and vendopform(it may be in any language). How i can do this, my mind has empty now to think this. Can any body help me to sort this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a SOAP service (which it sounds like you are, and I feel sorry for you ;)), try starting by looking at PHP's SOAP extension:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

If you can create something more RESTful, Ruby on Rails does a good job at allowing you to throw together a quick and dirty web service without too many headaches, but even in PHP you can create RESTful APIs pretty easily.

You can read the HTTP request body via e.g. `fgets(STDIN)` if your requests will accept XML as a POST/PUT format.

But yes, your question is too broad to provide anything more than nudges towards the tools you might choose to use.

Comment: I mean just i want to create a webservice that will work in PHP 5.2 with out any conflict

Comment: Your question is too broad. You'll need to be more specific with what you need help with.  Web services are a big topic.